# Browser is loading two images - one for srcset, one for src (Chrome 41 et al)

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, safari, srcset

I'm using the srcset attribute on a web page I'm developing.

```
<img src="img/picture-820x496.jpg" 
    srcset="img/picture-820x496.jpg 1200w, 
    img/picture-374x226.jpg 992w, 
    img/picture-305x185.jpg 768w, 
    img/picture-707x428.jpg 300w" />
```

If I check which resources get loaded with the page, I see that Chrome 41 as well as FF using the polyfill as well as Safari 7 always load the image twice - once the full resolution and once the according size from the srcset attribute. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please file a test case where you see this happening in Chrome? For non-supporting browsers the 'src' will trigger a download before the polyfill does its thing, but in Chrome that shouldn't be the case

Comment: little late. i use a transparent gif for the source `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==">`

Comment: i have observed the same problem. additionally, i'm using art-directions of images for different screen sizes with varying width/height relations, which makes the problem even worse since the wrong art direction is loaded and displayed initially but doesn't even fit into the layout. of course the effect can only be seen when using network throttling.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem, I found that if the `src` image was not one of those available in the `srcset` images the browser would load the `src` image regardless. The solution was to ensure the `src` image url matched one of the `srcset` images urls.

As an aside - as I understand the spec the `w` value following the image url should match (roughly) the width of the image. This allows the browser to best determine the image to display based on the `sizes` attribute and device pixel density. So you should probably alter the `w` values in your markup and add the `sizes` attribute (which allows you let the browser know the rendered image size using media queries and a fallback ie. `(min-width: 640px) 600px, 50vw`). Consider the example below:

```
<img src="img/picture-820x496.jpg" 
    srcset="img/picture-820x496.jpg 820w,
    img/picture-707x428.jpg 707w, 
    img/picture-374x226.jpg 374w, 
    img/picture-305x185.jpg 305w"
    sizes="100vw">
```