# Dynamically setting an image's srcset and src attributes triggers one request too many

Tags: javascript, html, image, responsive-design, srcset

I'm going for a lazy loading solution where an `<img>`'s `src` and `srcset` attributes are both set dynamically.

If an image has its `src` and `srcset` attributes both already present in the HTML (traditional), then a srcset-capable browser will safely ignore the `src` and only trigger one request, picked from the srcset list. ([this guy says it works](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/#comment-1585619), but two requests being triggered from HTML was indeed a [Chrome bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715791/browser-is-loading-two-images-one-for-srcset-one-for-src-chrome-41-et-al) until recently.)

```html
<img src=""
    data-lazy="fotos/000_180x120.jpg"
    data-lazy-srcset="fotos/000_180x120.jpg 180w,
    fotos/000_360x240.jpg 360w,
    fotos/000_720x480.jpg 720w,
    fotos/000_1080x720.jpg 1080w,
    fotos/000_1440x960.jpg 1440w,
    fotos/000_2160x1440.jpg 2160w"
    sizes="(min-width: 700px) 700px,
    100vw">
```

`src` is initially empty. In JavaScript both `src` and `srcset` attributes get set to the values in the `data-` attributes.

Now, unlike when the attributes are already set in the html, setting both attributes triggers two requests. This goes for whichever attribute is set first. It's understandable that setting `src` before setting `srcset` will already fire off one request.

What I want is to set `srcset` and then have a srcset-capable browser find its match, while ignoring the `src` attribute that is set afterwards and is meant as a fallback for other browsers.

Does anyone have experience with lazy-loading a srcset + fallback?